# Run Boost process with restrictions

Tags: c++, boost, process, permissions

I run a process thanks to the Boost library with this code using the `boost::process::child` class. My program works well. I am launching a process done by someone else, and I only need to send things on its stdin, and read its stdout. But I consider I cannot trust the child process owner, so I would like the process to be able to communicate with my main process with standard input/output, but I would like to prevent him from creating files, starting other processes (running command in terminal), or making other unsafe things.

I saw some ways to achieve that, but they use other APIs, and I cannot apply that to my boost process. I want my program to be cross-platform (Windows + Linux).

So, is there any way to achieve that, thanks to the boost library, or with other libraries (but which would be appropriate using the child class from the `boost::process` library) ?

EDIT: I would like my program to be easily given to a "ordinary" person. So I cannot use a solution which would imply the user to install other things than my executable (and possibly some libraries/data in a folder)

Comment: If you don't trust the program you start, perhaps you could start it in a VM or container?

Comment: Is there any way to start a child proccess in a VM by keeping my main process outside of this VM? If not, I fear that the child can manipulate the result of my program in some way. In addition, I think a VM would be too "big" for what I want since a want as much performances as possible, and this would slow me. And what kind of container are you speaking about? Have you in mind a crossplatform library that could enable me to start the boost process in this container?

Comment: Take a look at vagrant or docker. Perhaps one of those will work. At least you can start programs inside the container from the outside with vagrant. Not sure about docker.

Comment: Okay, I had a look at vagrant, but it's quite annoying me since it is "big stuff", so it will make the portability of my program more complex (people who will need this program would certainly need to install some stuff beside), and as I said, I hope it will not slow down the process and the communication between main and child processes. So it would be great if there was a "lighter" solution (library...). Despite that, I will install it and make some tests in case there is no other solution.

Comment: And I saw I will need to call something like "vagrant child.exe" when everything will be set up. Can you confirm that the input and output streams will go "through" the valgrind command, so that I can still communicate from my main process with the child process?

Comment: Sorry, but I looked at more deeply how does vagrant work, and it's even more "big" than what I thought before. So I don't think I will go in this direction. I would like my program to be given to anyone through an executable (possibly with a folder) for its use. Using vagrant will make things impossible. So any "lighter" solution is welcomed. I will edit my question in order to emphasize this aspect of my issue.